# nested loop that displays the same country multiple times in an html table

Tags: angular

To put it simply, I would like to obtain this type of result.

[image]

I managed to display each element in the HTML table:

[image]

The problem is that I display the country several times...

I don't know how I can display it only once?

I share you the JSON file:

```
 REGROUPEMENT = [
    {
      TYPEVALUE: 11,
      ASSETCATLABEL: 'Actions',
      CURRENCY: 'EUR',
      AMOUNT: 1646956.5,
      PERCENTAGE: 79.23,
      ELEMENT: [
        {
          LABEL: 'AB INBEV',
          TYPEVALUE: 11,
          ASSETCATLABEL: 'Actions',
          INSTRCURRENCY: 'EUR',
          AVERAGEDPRICE: 6,
          QUANTITY: 100,
          LASTPRICE: 57.14,
          PRICEVARIATION: 852.33,
          ACCRUEDINTERESTS: 0,
          VALORIZATION: 5714,
          PERCENTAGE: 0.27,
          PAYS: 1,
          PAYS_LIB: 'Belgique',
          GARANTIE: 0,
          VALORIZATIONEUR: 5714,
          DIFFEREUR: 5114,
        },
        {
          LABEL: 'BELUGA',
          TYPEVALUE: 11,
          ASSETCATLABEL: 'Actions',
          INSTRCURRENCY: 'EUR',
          AVERAGEDPRICE: 2.54,
          QUANTITY: 1000,
          LASTPRICE: 2.7,
          PRICEVARIATION: 6.29,
          ACCRUEDINTERESTS: 0,
          VALORIZATION: 2700,
          PERCENTAGE: 0.12,
          PAYS: 1,
          PAYS_LIB: 'Belgique',
          GARANTIE: 0,
          VALORIZATIONEUR: 2700,
          DIFFEREUR: 160,
        },
        {
          LABEL: 'LVMH',
          TYPEVALUE: 11,
          ASSETCATLABEL: 'Actions',
          INSTRCURRENCY: 'EUR',
          AVERAGEDPRICE: 545.4545,
          QUANTITY: 1100,
          LASTPRICE: 728.4,
          PRICEVARIATION: 33.54,
          ACCRUEDINTERESTS: 0,
          VALORIZATION: 801240,
          PERCENTAGE: 38.54,
          PAYS: 4,
          PAYS_LIB: 'France',
          GARANTIE: 0,
          VALORIZATIONEUR: 801240,
          DIFFEREUR: 201240,
        },
        {
          LABEL: 'SOLVAY BE',
          TYPEVALUE: 11,
          ASSETCATLABEL: 'Actions',
          INSTRCURRENCY: 'EUR',
          AVERAGEDPRICE: 85.4854,
          QUANTITY: 5150,
          LASTPRICE: 100.55,
          PRICEVARIATION: 17.62,
          ACCRUEDINTERESTS: 0,
          VALORIZATION: 517832.5,
          PERCENTAGE: 24.91,
          PAYS: 1,
          PAYS_LIB: 'Belgique',
          GARANTIE: 0,
          VALORIZATIONEUR: 517832.5,
          DIFFEREUR: 77582.5,
        },
        {
          LABEL: 'WILH WILHELMSEN HOLDING A',
          TYPEVALUE: 11,
          ASSETCATLABEL: 'Actions',
          INSTRCURRENCY: 'NOK',
          AVERAGEDPRICE: 230,
          QUANTITY: 15000,
          LASTPRICE: 230,
          PRICEVARIATION: 0,
          ACCRUEDINTERESTS: 0,
          VALORIZATION: 3450000,
          PERCENTAGE: 15.37,
          PAYS: 29,
          PAYS_LIB: 'Norvège',
          GARANTIE: 0,
          VALORIZATIONEUR: 319470,
          DIFFEREUR: 0,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

In Html-Angular

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <h2 class="pt-3 pb-3">HTML Table</h2>

  <table class="mb-5">
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Denomination</th>
      <th>Dev</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Average</th>
      <th>Change in %</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Estimate</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>Sale</th>
    </tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let instrument of REGROUPEMENT">
      <ng-container *ngIf="instrument.TYPEVALUE === 11">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7">{{ instrument.ASSETCATLABEL }}</td>
          <td>{{ instrument.AMOUNT }}</td>
          <td>{{ instrument.PERCENTAGE }}%</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of instrument.ELEMENT">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7">{{ item.PAYS_LIB }}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.QUANTITY }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.LABEL }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.INSTRCURRENCY }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.LASTPRICE }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.AVERAGEDPRICE }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.PRICEVARIATION }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.ACCRUEDINTERESTS }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.VALORIZATIONEUR }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.PERCENTAGE }}%</td>
          <td>{{ item.DIFFEREUR }}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

I created a reproduction on Stackblitz => https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-z6v4p8-m62asu?file=src/app/todo/todo.component.html

If you have a solution, I'm really interested.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your REGROUPEMENT array static or coming from any other service like backend/database?

Comment: Yes, it comes from a webservice.

Comment: how long can be your json array of REGROUPEMENT?

Comment: Normally there should be no other countries to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REGROUPEMENT array is needed to  be modified. As PAYS_LIB key is differentiating each row, we will modify the existing array acc to it.

I'd prefer modifying the array on backend i.e. do all the heavy lifting at backend and then send it to frontend.
For now, I have modified the array for you.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.REGROUPEMENT_2 = this.alterRegroupArray(this.REGROUPEMENT);
}

alterRegroupArray(arr: any) {
  arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
  let pays_lib: any = {};
  let pays_lib2: any = [];
  
  arr.forEach((item: any) => {
    item.ELEMENT.forEach((subItem: any) => {
      if(pays_lib[subItem.PAYS_LIB]) {
        pays_lib[subItem.PAYS_LIB].push(subItem);
      } else {
        pays_lib[subItem.PAYS_LIB] = [];
        pays_lib[subItem.PAYS_LIB].push(subItem);
      }

      Object.keys(pays_lib).forEach((key, i) => {
        pays_lib2[i] = {key: key, value: pays_lib[key]}; 
      });
    });
    
    item.ELEMENT = pays_lib2;
  })
  return arr;
}
```

Now, the modified array looks like this: -

```
[
    {
        "TYPEVALUE": 11,
        "ASSETCATLABEL": "Actions",
        "CURRENCY": "EUR",
        "AMOUNT": 1646956.5,
        "PERCENTAGE": 79.23,
        "ELEMENT": [
            {
                "key": "Belgique",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "LABEL": "AB INBEV",
                        "TYPEVALUE": 11,
                        "ASSETCATLABEL": "Actions",
                        "INSTRCURRENCY": "EUR",
                        "AVERAGEDPRICE": 6,
                        "QUANTITY": 100,
                        "LASTPRICE": 57.14,
                        "PRICEVARIATION": 852.33,
                        "ACCRUEDINTERESTS": 0,
                        "VALORIZATION": 5714,
                        "PERCENTAGE": 0.27,
                        "PAYS": 1,
                        "PAYS_LIB": "Belgique",
                        "GARANTIE": 0,
                        "VALORIZATIONEUR": 5714,
                        "DIFFEREUR": 5114
                    },
                    {
                        "LABEL": "BELUGA",
                        "TYPEVALUE": 11,
                        "ASSETCATLABEL": "Actions",
                        "INSTRCURRENCY": "EUR",
                        "AVERAGEDPRICE": 2.54,
                        "QUANTITY": 1000,
                        "LASTPRICE": 2.7,
                        "PRICEVARIATION": 6.29,
                        "ACCRUEDINTERESTS": 0,
                        "VALORIZATION": 2700,
                        "PERCENTAGE": 0.12,
                        "PAYS": 1,
                        "PAYS_LIB": "Belgique",
                        "GARANTIE": 0,
                        "VALORIZATIONEUR": 2700,
                        "DIFFEREUR": 160
                    },
                    {
                        "LABEL": "SOLVAY BE",
                        "TYPEVALUE": 11,
                        "ASSETCATLABEL": "Actions",
                        "INSTRCURRENCY": "EUR",
                        "AVERAGEDPRICE": 85.4854,
                        "QUANTITY": 5150,
                        "LASTPRICE": 100.55,
                        "PRICEVARIATION": 17.62,
                        "ACCRUEDINTERESTS": 0,
                        "VALORIZATION": 517832.5,
                        "PERCENTAGE": 24.91,
                        "PAYS": 1,
                        "PAYS_LIB": "Belgique",
                        "GARANTIE": 0,
                        "VALORIZATIONEUR": 517832.5,
                        "DIFFEREUR": 77582.5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "France",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "LABEL": "LVMH",
                        "TYPEVALUE": 11,
                        "ASSETCATLABEL": "Actions",
                        "INSTRCURRENCY": "EUR",
                        "AVERAGEDPRICE": 545.4545,
                        "QUANTITY": 1100,
                        "LASTPRICE": 728.4,
                        "PRICEVARIATION": 33.54,
                        "ACCRUEDINTERESTS": 0,
                        "VALORIZATION": 801240,
                        "PERCENTAGE": 38.54,
                        "PAYS": 4,
                        "PAYS_LIB": "France",
                        "GARANTIE": 0,
                        "VALORIZATIONEUR": 801240,
                        "DIFFEREUR": 201240
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "Norvège",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "LABEL": "WILH WILHELMSEN HOLDING A",
                        "TYPEVALUE": 11,
                        "ASSETCATLABEL": "Actions",
                        "INSTRCURRENCY": "NOK",
                        "AVERAGEDPRICE": 230,
                        "QUANTITY": 15000,
                        "LASTPRICE": 230,
                        "PRICEVARIATION": 0,
                        "ACCRUEDINTERESTS": 0,
                        "VALORIZATION": 3450000,
                        "PERCENTAGE": 15.37,
                        "PAYS": 29,
                        "PAYS_LIB": "Norvège",
                        "GARANTIE": 0,
                        "VALORIZATIONEUR": 319470,
                        "DIFFEREUR": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As per modified array, We can easily follow parent-child structure in html like this: -

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <h2 class="pt-3 pb-3">HTML Table</h2>

  <table class="mb-5">
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Denomination</th>
      <th>Dev</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Average</th>
      <th>Change in %</th>
      <th>Interest</th>
      <th>Estimate</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>Sale</th>
    </tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let instrument of REGROUPEMENT_2">
      <ng-container *ngIf="instrument.TYPEVALUE === 11">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7">{{ instrument.ASSETCATLABEL }}</td>
          <td>{{ instrument.AMOUNT }}</td>
          <td>{{ instrument.PERCENTAGE }}%</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of instrument.ELEMENT">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7">{{ item['key'] }}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <ng-container>
          <tr *ngFor="let subItem of item.value">
            <td>{{ subItem.QUANTITY }}</td>
            <td>{{ subItem.LABEL }}</td>
            <td>{{ subItem.INSTRCURRENCY }}</td>
            <td>{{ subItem.LASTPRICE }}</td>
            <td>{{ subItem.AVERAGEDPRICE }}</td>
            <td>{{ subItem.PRICEVARIATION }}</td>
            <td>{{ subItem.ACCRUEDINTERESTS }}</td>
            <td>{{ subItem.VALORIZATIONEUR }}</td>
            <td>{{ subItem.PERCENTAGE }}%</td>
            <td>{{ subItem.DIFFEREUR }}</td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

This will give you the desired output: -

[image]

I hope this will do the job for you.